# How to render 2 views of different actions of different controllers in Zend 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got 2 controllers.

1. CategoryController

   ```
   public function readAction()
   {
      $id = $this->_request->getParam('id');
      $categoryModel = new Model_Category();
      if(!$categoryModel)
      {
          throw new \Exception(__METHOD__.', could not create category model');
      }
      $category = $categoryModel->getCategory($id);
      $parent = $category->findParentRow(new Model_Category());
      if(!$parent)
      {
          $this->view->parent = 'no parent';
      }
      else
      {
          $this->view->parent = $parent->name;
      }

      // I need to pass category object to read.phtml of controller category
      // so that each attributes of the category could be displayed.
      $this->view->category = $category;

      // Below the category section, I also need to list all 
      // the business entities which are the child rows of that category. 
      // So I forward to controller business, action list.
      // Normally I use list.phtml in controller business to do that.
      $this->_forward('list', 'business');
    }
   ```
2. BusinessController

But after I call _forward, the read.phtml is not diplayed, I could see only the list.phtml of controller business.
My question is, what could I do if I want to call read.phtml of controller category, and list.phtml of controller business at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render current action before forwarding:

```
public function readAction()
{
    // ...
    $this->render();
    $this->_forward('list', 'business');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your read.phtml view, you could use :

echo $this->render('business/list.phtml');

to display the other view.

Comment: this does not work in my case, because in my list view, i also need to put sort, filter, and pagination controls there. I mean, I don't need just to render the view, but also need to pass some data into it. Anyhow, thanks you so much for your reponse ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$viewRenderer->setResponseSegment('someOtherThanContent')` and render it lately in layout using

```
$this->layout()->someOtherThanContent;
```